# What advantages has a local same-computer Spark cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, docker

I am running a Apache Spark installation inside [Docker](https://store.docker.com/community/images/gettyimages/spark). Thanks to Docker Compose, I am able to set up a local cluster - by example - declaring one part of it as a master and the other container as a worker or slave. This instance of Docker Compose is installed locally on my computer and I am targeting the same local image during the setup. So both containers are running on my local system successfully.

Since I am not a professional in cluster computing I am not absolutely sure but I think that Docker Compose might bring the possibility to set up clusters over multiple computers - and I think that is the reason for it.
Connecting a few computers to parallelize calculations would decrease calc time and so on...

Nevertheless, is it of any use to execute a cluster on the same local machine? For other reason then testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much the only reason to do something is simulating actual cluster for testing and development. While `local` mode is normally used for this purpose, it doesn't really behave like a real cluster, and certain issues can be really hard to spot. Also, unlike with local mode, it allows you to simulate different failure scenarios.

When it comes to production, there is really not much use for that. Supported cluster managers already provide decent containerization support, and actually know how to integrate with Spark.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the spark with containers, check the [Spark-on-Kubernetes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html). Since 2.3.0 Spark can use the Kubernetes as the native scheduler. Afaik, currently the Pyspark or R bindings are not there and it can't run in the client mode (so you can't use the interactive shell, nor notebooks), but I expect these features to be there in future versions of Spark and Kubernetes is a de facto standard for containers orchestration.

I wouldn't recommend using Docker Compose, but I may be quite biased.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I have experimented a little considering a small local Spark cluster. Surprisingly, the parallelization advantages on a single device have already worked out for me. So there is a measurable improvement in speed in certain cases.